# Where to store the database tables names?

Tags: database, database-design

Should it be considered as a "best practice" to store the database tables names in a config file?

I do understand that storing the tables names in a config file makes future updates easier: if table is renamed, there is only one file that will need to be updated.

However, let say retrieving a table name is done using a function like this one: getTableName_Customers() (assuming the table name is Customers)

If the table Customers is renamed as Clients, we should also update the function name as getTableName_Clients(), which means all the occurrences of getTableName_Customers() will also "have" to be renamed in the source code.

Which to me ends up as being the same a renaming all the occurrences of a hard coded table name in all the source files.

Should the tables names be stored in a config file or should it be left as "hard coded" in the source code?
Is there any best practice on that matter?

Thank you

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Renaming is *basically* a bad habit. Adding an extra layer of indiriction *could* help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most development environments where the database is separate from your code base such as [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)) & [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL), Yes, you must manually update your codebase to be in sync with name changes in your database.

Not an issue in development environments integrated with the database such as [4D](http://www.4D.com/) or [Filemaker](http://www.Filemaker.com) where name changes percolate throughout the code base automatically.

## Database migration tool

You may want to learn about database migration tools such as [*Flyway*](https://flywaydb.org) or [*Liquibase*](http://www.liquibase.org) or others.

These tools provide an organized way to define your database, add/drop/modify tables, add/drop/modify columns, add/drop/modify indexes, and so on. The tool looks at an existing database and automatically applies any not-yet-applied modifications.

The tool tracks database migration scripts (SQL or other such as XML or Java code, etc.) in files. You may choose to keep those files along with your app’s source code if that makes sense in your situation.

So when you decide to rename the `Customer` table to `Client`, you can update your Java code with some search-and-replace operations. At the same time, write the database modification script. Rest assured your database migration tool will automatically apply the latest script when encountering a database in need of the update.

Yes, with a migration tool you still need to make the name change in two places (app code & migration script), but you can conveniently do both at once and not worry about deployment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> If the table `Customers` is renamed as `Clients`, we should also update the function name as `getTableName_Clients()`.

It depends on what prompted the rename. If it's a "technical" rename (rename `customers` to `acme_customers` in a multi-tenant database), then you don't rename your function, of course. That's the whole purpose of abstraction. Similar for `customers` => `clients`. It appears to be just a different name for the same thing.

If, however, the name was caused by "bigger" changes, then it's better to rename the function too, to reflect the changes (say, now `customers` is `users` with a referenced `customer_profile`).

Comment: Thank you. I have always prefered to work with functions having names that  "literally" describes what is the entity/object/"thing" it is pointing at. Maybe I should my mind in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you are trying to optimize and how your application connects to the DB.

If you are trying to create an easy to maintain program that directly accesses the database you could use such an approach, assuming an operational environment where database table names often change. However this approach would sacrifice performance requiring function calls in every query creation. E.g.

```
String query="select * from "+getTableName_Customers();
```

The performance can be easily fixed with a caching mechanism, however it would require more effort.
Renaming a function should be an easy task given the refactoring toolset of most IDEs.

Using a single class to write all queries and tables is a common practice when programs manage databases directly.

As a best practice however it would be best to use a persistence framework such as Hibernate (http://hibernate.org/). This would abstract most of the maintenance work and offer other advantages.